# Can you create an integer custom field in Salesforce.com?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, custom-fields

I want to create an integer custom field on an object. I see that I can create a custom field of "Number" but that seems to return a decimal type. Mostly this is annoying as I plan to use the field as an Integer and everywhere I'm using it in code I have to cast it to an Integer. None of the other field types seem to be even close - the only other field type that even seems to hold a numeric type is Currency.

I've adjusted the number after the decimal fields to (3,0) - three numbers before the decimal, zero numbers after the decimal. It's still returning a decimal.

Is it even possible to create an integer? Is casting it every time I need it considered the "best practice"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't create an integer type. As you've discovered, Number results in a decimal. If you'd like to treat it as an integer you just cast it.

Comment: I was afraid of that, but thought I would check. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ryan, just in case you want an easy way to put this on a VF page without a controller where you can cast it, you can get 0 dp displayed by using {!FLOOR(TheField__c)}.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the field in Visualforce, make sure you use `<apex:outputField>` or `<apex:inputField>`, as opposed to `<apex:outputText>` and `<apex:inputText>`, which will render out the decimal place. Ran into this issue not long ago.